# How to style a view component to add space between two buttons?

Tags: react-native

I'm new to front end development in react native. Just trying to get the hang of stylesheet. I've placed two buttons inside a view with the following styling.

```
buttonscontainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    }
```

[image]

Here's the full jsx and styling

```
<Modal transparent={true} visible={true}>
            <View style={styles.dimmedBackground}>
                <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
                    <Text>type something</Text>
                    <TextInput style={styles.input} />
                    <View style={styles.buttonsContainer}>
                        <Button title="Cancel" color="coral" />
                        <Button title="Add" color="coral" />
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        </Modal>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    dimmedBackground: {
        backgroundColor: '#000000aa',
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    modalContainer: {
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        margin: 35,
        padding: 30,
        borderRadius: 10,
    },
    input: {
        marginBottom: 10,
        paddingVertical: 6,
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        borderBottomColor: '#ddd',
    },
    buttonsContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    },
});
```

I've been trying to create space between both buttons for a while now, quite lost on how to achieve this.

How should I be styling the view component wrapping the two buttons so that there is a bit of space horizontally between the both of them? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 'space-between' for justification, provide a width

```
 buttonscontainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        marginHorizontal: 5,
        width:'40%',
        alignSelf:'flex-end'
    },
```

Comment: Okay interesting. So in situations where space is desired between items, `justifyContent: 'space-between'` should be used, and then alignment on the view can be controlled else where like with `alignSelf`? This is great btw.

Comment: Well thats one option, also you cna wrap the button in a view and provide a marginLeft as well

Comment: I really enjoy the direct width control. Very helpful.